# apex:pageblocksection onclick=expand , how to achive this

Tags: visualforce

My requirement is display account and coressponding contacts in visualforce page.  so i used pageblocksection . I used javascript code for default non-expand of data.

If any one clicks on "leftside button"  then data expanding and  showing.  Thats well and working.   i want if a person clicks on text of pageblocksection title or pageblocksection  empty area then it should expand.

please help me what to do for it,  i started to write javascript code, but confused what to do write in it.

```
<apex:page controller="actocons" tabStyle="Account">

<script>

function showdata()
{

}
</script>
    <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:repeat value="{!acct}" var="a">

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1" title="{!a.name}" onclick="showdata()" >
            <script>twistSection(document.getElementById("{!$Component.section1}").childNodes[0].childNodes[0]); </script>

            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a.Contacts}" var="c" id="j1">
                <apex:column value="{!c.id}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.lastname}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.email}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>   
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

apex code:-

```
public class actocons
{
    public list<account> acct{set;get;}
    public actocons()
    {
        acct=[select id,name,(select id,lastname,email from contacts)from account limit 10 offset 4];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add an output panel around the block and having the on click event trigger a javascript function? Also, it might be easier to use a class instead of an id. If you add more id's above it later, then it will break. You can use document.getElementsByClassName()[0] to grab the element and set it to be expanded. You would want to update the style if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my first look I thought it is quite easy. I can call the same javascript function on the click event of the `pageBlockSection` header. Then I realized the arrow is stopped working. Why. Because the arrow is inside the div and on clicking the arrow there are two javascript events comes into picture one from image and another from `div`. I planned to stop the event propagation. But Salesforce doesn't provide access to the original `twistSection` function. So I tried to override it with a new function and added the extra code to stop the event propagation. And it is working as expected. User can click on the entire header to expand the section. Here is the updated VF code. Hope this will help.

**VF code**

```
<apex:page controller="actocons" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:repeat value="{!acct}" var="a">
            <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1" title="{!a.name}" onclick="document.getElementById('{!$Component.section1}').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].click();">
            <script>twistSection(document.getElementById("{!$Component.section1}").childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);document.getElementById("{!$Component.section1}").childNodes[0].style.cssText = "cursor:pointer;" </script>
            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a.Contacts}" var="c" id="j1">
                <apex:column value="{!c.id}" />
                <apex:column value="{!c.lastname}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.email}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>   
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
<script>
    twistSection = (function() {
        var cached_function = twistSection;

        return function(twisty, sectionId) {
            cached_function.apply(this, arguments); // use .apply() to call the original twistSection function provided by Salesforce
            if (event.stopPropagation) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                event.cancelBubble = true;
            }
        };
    }());

</script>    
</apex:page>
```

Though it is working. It is not recommended by Salesforce to use the Salesforce's core JavaScript libraries. Please see the link and warning below. Because you don't know when they change these libraries and your entire functionality will break.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181821&language=en_US

NOTE: At present, this functionality cannot be implemented via supported Visualforce/Apex methods. What's provided below is provided "as is" and can be used at your own risk, as it makes use of a function that is part of Salesforce's core JavaScript libraries, which are not meant to be used by developers as they may change without further notice.

Comment: thankyou very much. u code is fit for my requirement.   love u..........

Comment: @PuvvadaPrasanth Thanks, can you please mark it as answer and vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
    <apex:page controller="actocons" tabStyle="Account">

    <script>

    function showdata(object){ 
          document.getElementById(object.id).childNodes[1].style.display == "block" ? document.getElementById(object.id).childNodes[1].style.display = "none" : document.getElementById(object.id).childNodes[1].style.display = "block"; 

     }

    </script>
        <apex:pageBlock >

            <apex:repeat value="{!acct}" var="a">

                <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1" onclick="showdata(this);" title="{!a.name}">

                <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a.Contacts}" var="c" id="j1">
                    <apex:column value="{!c.id}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!c.lastname}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.email}" />
                </apex:pageBlockTable>  

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:page>
```

Its working for me.
Sorry for code formatting i was not able to format it better.

Comment: Prabhat read the question carefully Puvvada already mentioned that he wants the pageblocksection to be in non-expanded form. Only when user clicks on it it will expand. In your solution the pageblocksections are in expanded form by default. Secondly Puvvada wants that user can click anywhere in the header including the arrow image. In your solution the arrow image is not working.